# The script completed but the returned value is not a supported return type

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to get response from Google Script. But it gives me an error: **The script completed but the returned value is not a supported return type.**

Here's some script code:

```js
function doGet(e) {

  var result = 'ERROR PASSWORD';

  if (Pass(e)) {
    result = ParseRequest(e);
  }

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result);
}


function ParseRequest(e) {
  var result;

  if (!CheckOrAddData(e)) {
    result = 'FAILED';
  } else {
    result = 'ACTIVATED PROMOCODE';
  }

  return result;
}



function Pass(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(e.parameters.ssid);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('PASS');
  var sheetPass = sheet.getDataRange().getValue();

  if (e.parameters.pass == sheetPass)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}


function CheckOrAddData(e) {

  var promoCode = e.parameters.promocode;
  var nickName = e.parameters.username;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(e.parameters.ssid);

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('DATA');

  if (nickName == "") {
    return false;
  }

  var range = sheet.getRange('A1:B');
  var rows = range.getNumRows();
  var values = range.getDisplayValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] == promoCode) {
      if (values[i][1] == 'NO') {
        var cell = range.getCell(i + 1, 2);
        cell.setValue(nickName);
        return true;
      }

      if (values[i][1] == nickName) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

This response that I get from [Hurl.it](https://www.hurl.it/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico">
      <title>Error</title>
      <style type="text/css">body {background-color: #fff; margin: 0; padding: 0;}.errorMessage {font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold; line-height: 150%; padding-top: 25px;}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div>
        <img src="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/logo.png">
        </div>
        <center>The script completed but the returned value is not a supported return type.</center>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I don't see a function named `Pass()`.  From this line: `if (Pass(e))`  You may want to add a `try/catch` block to return a default value if there is a server error.

Comment: Edited GS code, still not working outside editor. (Works fine when debugging). Returning default value - not good solution( So it's successfully editing Spreadsheet, but not returning value.

Comment: Try excluding the `getContent()` on newResults.

Comment: Without getContent() it will return object type.

Answer (score 6):

Your function `doGet` is trying to return `newResult.getContent()` which is a string. But `doGet` is not allowed to return a string. It must return an object of an acceptable class: [HtmlOutput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output) (created with HtmlService) or [TextOutput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/text-output) (created with ContentService).

So, it should be `return newResult;`  not `return newResult.getContent();`

Comment: Changed doGet() to this: http://pastebin.com/LtcV94bU but it still not working (((

Comment: "not working"... do you know you can get instant email notifications of script failures? Also, there's a reference to function `CheckOrAddData` and you haven't posted that function.

Comment: Updated Google Script. Both TextOutput and HtmlOutput not working. I don't have any notifications on my email. Sorry but i really don't know where is problem

Comment: I am returning string value, but it still gives the same error

Answer (score 2):

I made my doGet() function async (without thinking too much about it) and then spent an hour trying to fix this error "The script completed but the returned value is not a supported return type."

```
async function doGet(event) {...}
```

Obviously, returning a Promise is not supported. Don't make this function async and hope that it works.